# Stylistic / rhetorical device used by Obama over and over

Tags: speech, rhetoric

After reading some of his speeches, I see one rhetorical device used over and over by Obama, some examples for it include:

- large or small
- wealthy or poor
- able or disabled
- gay or straight
- young or old

What is it called? Is it a simple antithesis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think **[juxtaposition](http://literarydevices.net/juxtaposition/)** is the name of this literary device.

*“It was the best of times, it was the worst of times, it was the age of wisdom, it was the age of foolishness."* Charles Dickens

Comment: Thank you, wouldn't have found that in most style guides I think.

Answer (score 1):

The technical term is [*merism*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merism), the literary device of referring to a thing by enumerating some or all of its constituents.

A particular form of *merism*, which employs two polar terms to designate a totality, is frequently employed in the Hebrew Bible. Think for instance of the Tree of knowledge of good and evil, where *knowledge of good and evil* is understood by Hebrew scholars to mean not the ability to distinguish good from evil but the knowledge of **all** things.

It is frequently remarked that Obama's rhetoric owes a great deal to the pulpit style of African-American preachers, and I think it is no great stretch to see his fondness for this device as similarly founded.

Comment: The totality of human knowledge: https://i.imgur.com/oEXYFZw.jpg

Answer (score 0):

**Syncrisis** [(Rhet.) A figure of speech in which opposite things or persons are compared. --Crabb.](http://www.dictionary30.com/meaning/Syncrisis)